# Selenium (python): how do I fetch only the first element with href

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors

With the following code I am fetching links I need from within some  items but for unknown reasons within it there are TWO identical <a tags with the identical contents.

```
<span class="risultato">
<a href="/atto/serie_generale/caricaDettaglioAtto/originario?atto.dataPubblicazioneGazzetta=2021-12-31&amp;atto.codiceRedazionale=21A07813&amp;elenco30giorni=false">
<span class="data">
ORDINANZA 31 dicembre 2021
</span>
</a>
<a href="/atto/serie_generale/caricaDettaglioAtto/originario?atto.dataPubblicazioneGazzetta=2021-12-31&amp;atto.codiceRedazionale=21A07813&amp;elenco30giorni=false">
Ulteriori misure  urgenti  in  materia  di  contenimento  e  gestione
dell'emergenza  epidemiologica  da  COVID-19  nelle  Regioni   Lazio,
Liguria,  Lombardia,  Marche,  Piemonte,  Sicilia,  Veneto  e   nelle
Province autonome di Trento e Bolzano. (21A07813) 
<span class="riferimento">
</span>
<span class="pagina">Pag. 17</span>
</a>
</span>
```

How can I fetch only one of them?

```
atti = [
        my_elem.get_attribute("href")
        for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.risultato > a")
            )
        )
    ]
```

Comment: Can you paste the HTML, as opposed to showing an image of it? It will make it much easier to reproduce.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark you are right. Corrected! Happy 2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch the first href you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *CSS_SELECTOR* as `first-child`:

  ```
  for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.risultato > a:first-child"))):
  ```
- *CSS_SELECTOR* as `first-of-type`:

  ```
  for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.risultato > a:first-of-type"))):
  ```